# What is the Best Way to Create a Global Variable?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a simple question, but its is very important to my project: What is the best way to create a global variable?

In my project, when the user will be authenticated, I build all web menus according with his profile, like claims or roles (I create my own claims), and I start to build the menu, with the specifics pages wich the user have permission to access.

In my filter method, I always check in the database if the user has the permission to access the menu.

What I wanna know is if have a possibility to put this list of menus in a global variable, like a Session ("/) or Application, because I dont wanna have to go to the database to check those permissions, and in this case is better if I could get this list in the server memory or something like that...

Regards.

Comment: The best way to create a global variable is not to create one.

Comment: Global variables should be avoided. You could use service class that has a method you invoke to get this info. That service method would hit the database or do what ever setup it needs to, and cache the results in a private static collection. You should really avoid a public static property that is truly global. It will bite you in the butt later on.

Comment: You should be checking the role of the user. If the user meets a specific role, then show the menus? Why do you not want this approach?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Global variables in c#.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445436/global-variables-in-c-net)

Comment: In that project, all the menus are configurable by a View with a table in the dabatase. How can I cache the results in a 'private static collection'? Because I wanna get my list of menus and put it in a 'global variable' to can take it everytime I want! In each page which user clicks, I must check if the user has the access and it is better if I could just read this 'global variable' in my filter method instead of to get that by the database.

Comment: Isn't this what caches are for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to handle your situation is with a child action. You simply create an action in some controller in your project. Since this deals with user-level access, I'll use `AccountController`.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult UserMenu()
{
    if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated())
    {
        // logic to select your menu from database
        return View(menu);
    }

    // optionally you can return a different menu for anonymous users here
    return Content("");
}
```

Then, you create the `UserMenu.cshtml` view in your `Views\Account` directory. In this view, you'll simply use the model instance you passed in (`menu` above) to render just portion of your site navigation the `menu` object applies to.

Finally, in your layout, wherever you want this menu to appear, call:

```
@Html.Action("UserMenu", "Account");
```

If you want to only have this run once (really better put as "occasionally"), then you can utilize caching. Just add the following additional attribute to your child action:

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600, VaryByCustom = "User")]
```

There's no built in way to vary the cache by a particular user, so you have to create a custom vary. It's relatively easy though. Just add something like the following to Global.asax:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string arg) 
{ 
    if(arg.ToLower() == "user") 
    { 
        if (context.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated())
        {
            return context.User.Identity.Name;
        }

        return null;
    } 

    return base.GetVaryByCustomString(context, arg); 
}
```

Then, MVC will cache the output of the `UserMenu` action for each unique user for 1 hour (3600 seconds), meaning any other requests by the same user will not invoke the action or send any queries to your database until the cache has expired.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what I want! I have 2 simple questions: 1) This 'OutputCache' is a 'nice thing' to the application or is a 'bad thing', if you know what I mean... 2) In the 'GetVaryByCustomString' method, what's the difference between 'return null' and 'return context.User.Identity.Name'? Because the both make no difference to execute the 'ChildAction'...