# Trying to delete messages from an array of words

Tags: c#, discord.net

I'm trying to check if the user posted a message with a blacklisted word in it and delete the message if the blacklisted word is found however i'm not able to check for the words in any way.i assigned the `OnMessageReceived` callback to the `MessageReceived` function. I'm kinda new to this so it might be an easy answer but i've been trying to figure it out for the past 2 days.

```
    private async Task OnMessageReceived(SocketMessage msg)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < blacklistedWords.Length; i++)
        {
            if (msg.Content.Contains(blacklistedWords[i]))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(msg.Author.ToString() + " did a bad");
                await msg.Channel.DeleteMessagesAsync(); //I can't find out what to pass in here to delete the message
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the line `i = blacklistedWords.Length;` doing?

Comment: Pass `msg` to that function you're not sure what to pass to. And this seems to be running only once, which makes the loop useless because this will always run once

Comment: i tried passing the `msg` but it won't only work with that. I deleted the `i = blacklistedWords.Length;` aswell

Comment: @ComxT it's still there

Comment: Updated it in my code, forgot to edit here sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I figured it out. I just needed to get the message I was trying to delete first. Here's the final code

```
    private async Task OnMessageReceived(SocketMessage msg)
    {
        foreach (var word in blacklistedWords)
        {
            if (msg.Content.Contains(word))
            {
                var messagesToDelete = await msg.Channel.GetMessagesAsync(1).Flatten();
                await msg.Channel.DeleteMessagesAsync(messagesToDelete);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a global duplicate data structure and assigning the edited content into the data structure.  I.E

```
List<SocketMessageModel > mylist = new List<SocketMessageModel >();

private async Task OnMessageReceived(SocketMessage msg)
{
    SocketMessageModel msgModel = new SocketMessageModel();
    msgModel.Content = msg.Content;
    msgModel.Author = msg.Author;
    Boolean blackListCheck = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < blacklistedWords.Length; i++)
    {
            Console.WriteLine(msg.Author.ToString() + " did a bad");
            if (msg.Content.Contains(blacklistedWords[i]))
            {
                blackListCheck = true;
                break;
            }

    }

    if (blackListCheck == false)
    {
        mylist.add(msg);
    }

}
public class SocketMessageModel
{
    public string Author {get; set; }
    public string Content {get; set; }
}
```

With this solution, all messages containing blacklisted words will be excluded from the global data structure.  Then, you can do whatever you want with all of the messages stored in a simple list after you parse each message.

Comment: Do i need a using statement for the `List<SocketMessage > mylist = new List<SocketMessage >();` because it's missing a directive or assembly reffrence, the `msg.Content` is read only and at `Convert.ToCharacter` it says that Convert doesn't have a definition for ToCharacter

Comment: Updated to reflect your comment.  Research how to declare global variables here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35083652/how-to-declare-a-variable-for-global-use

Comment: What i'm trying to do is delete the messages containing the blacklisted words so storing other words doesn't seem needed. I don't see where i go with this because before i updated from 0.9.6 i could do this although i had to pass in the string everytime